# Como não deixar que cadastre uma chave estrangeira qualquer?

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, tabela-banco-de-dados

Tenho um banco de dados de uma urna eletrônica com as seguintes tabelas:

- Eleitor(**Pk** titulodeeleior, nome )
- VotosComputados(**Fk** titulodeeleitor , voto)

Pelo meu conhecimento, a tabela `VotosComputados` não deve inserir uma `FK` qualquer, e sim uma que já exista na tabela `Eleitor`, porém estou fazendo um `INSERT` e ele está inserindo uma `FK` qualquer.

Resumindo:

Quando faço um `INSERT` na tabela que possui a chave estrangeira, ele está deixando eu inserir uma chave que não esteja cadastrada na tabela `Eleitor`.

Abaixo segue com criei minhas tabelas:

```
CREATE TABLE Eleitor(
titulodeeleitor VARCHAR(150) ,
nome VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL ,
primary key (titulodeeleitor)
);
create table votoscomputados(
titulodeeleitor varchar(150),
votoinserido int 
);
alter table votoscomputados add foreign key (titulodeeleitor) references Eleitor(titulodeeleitor);
```

Answer (score 1):

Primeiramente, uma chave primária não pode ser `VARCHAR` (até onde eu sei). Aconselho você criar um outro campo `id`, por exemplo, do tipo inteiro, e usá-lo como chave primária da tabela `Eleitor`. E para a chave estrangeira você deve usar um inteiro também. No caso, ficaria assim:

```
CREATE TABLE `eleitor` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulodeeleitor` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `nome` varchar(30) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `votoscomputados` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `votoinserido` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `eleitor` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `eleitor`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `votoscomputados`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD KEY `eleitor` (`eleitor`);

ALTER TABLE `eleitor`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `votoscomputados`
  MODIFY `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `votoscomputados`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `votoscomputados_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`eleitor`) REFERENCES `eleitor` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```